# How can I prevent this code to show me a randomly selected div twice or more in a row?

Tags: jquery, random

Im very new to jQuery and I already had a hard time doing just this. I have several Div's with the class ".figures" which are set to "display: none;" I would like to have the same effect like now, but without showing the same div twice or more in a row. I have to store the number somehow, so I can check wether it's the same as before, right? How can I do this?

Here's the code:

```
(function randomFade() {
var fadeDivs = $('.figures'),
    el = fadeDivs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * fadeDivs.length));
    el.fadeIn('1000').delay(2000).fadeOut('1000',randomFade); 
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could store the numbers of elemets but there is also another way.

You can add a class ".already-used" to an element that is being faded in:

```
el.fadeIn('1000').addClass('.already-used').delay(2000).fadeOut('1000',randomFade);
```

Then you should select only `.figures` elements without `.already-used` class:

```
var fadeDivs = $('.figures:not(.already-used)');
```

You could also remove the .`already-used` class right after the selector `var fadeDivs = $('.figures:not(.already-used)');` if u want to repeat the same element but not 2 times in a row:

```
$('.figures').removeClass('.already-used');
```

Or you can use more classes and change them step by step, cycle by cycle from higher to lower class number like:
`.already-used-3` change to `.already-used-2`, then to .`already-used-1`, then to no class if u dont want to repeat the same element more often than every fourth time. The selector would be:

```
var fadeDivs = $('.figures:not(.already-used-3):not(.already-used-2):not(.already-used-1)');
```

Comment: I couldn't use `$('.figures').removeClass('.already-used');` so I had to rewrite it like that: `el = fadeDivs.removeClass('.already-used');`

Comment: Why not? It should remove all the .already-used class from .figers elemt that have it and ignore the ements that don'h have the class.

Comment: This would work if i used another structure of code. But since I use `var fadeDivs = $('.figures'),` (look at the **,**) I couldn't use your version and had to adapt it like the other `el =`

You know what I mean now?

Answer (score 0):

I went on with the answers of "Incredible" and now make my own answer because I had to adjust his code a little to work with my code: Here is the solution that made it work for me:

```
(function randomFade() {
   var fadeDivs = $('.figures:not(.already-used)'),
   el = fadeDivs.removeClass('.already-used');
   el = fadeDivs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * fadeDivs.length));
   el.fadeIn('1000').addClass('.already-used').delay(2000).fadeOut('1000',randomFade);
})();
```